# Unable to turn off DirSync

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I went through the Hybrid Setup configuration, unaware that this would enable DirSync. I now want to disable AD synchronization again.

When I go to the Azure AD Admin Center and disable directory synchronization for our domain, the switch will go back to **Activated** right after it was deactivated.

I also tried disabling DirSync through PowerShell:

```
Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled -EnableDirSync $false -Verbose
```

This only results in the unhelpful error message:

> Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled : You cannot turn off Active Directory synchronization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After DirSync has been enabled for a domain, it can take up to 24 hours until you're able to disable it again.

- [I can't disable DirSync "You cannot turn off Active Directory Synchronization"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_dirservices/i-cant-disable-dirsync-you-cannot-turn-off-active/231c912c-018f-4a0d-87b5-338c499ddd79)
- [Unable to deactivate DirSync](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_dirservices/unable-to-deactivate-dirsync/b3dc1579-f235-41c7-96ae-2b175e3167e7)

In our specific case, we were able to disable it after approximately 12 hours.