# office 365 enable AD sync after disabling

Tags: active-directory, powershell, microsoft-office-365

To me this is a rather weird issue, I've managed to complete exactly what I wanted to do, however, I'm now at the stage I want to enable AD sync again. The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled -EnableDirSync $true
Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled : You cannot turn off Active Directory synchronization.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled -EnableDirSync $true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.DirSyncStatusChangeNotAllowedException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetDirSyncEnabled
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: The issue isn't that I'm looking to turn off ADsync, I've done this, I'm now looking to turn ADsync back on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to turn off DirSync](https://serverfault.com/questions/858719/unable-to-turn-off-dirsync)

Comment: @marsh-wiggle my issue isn't turning off DirSync, it's turning it back on.

Comment: The answer there is, that you have to wait about 24h before changing the state again. Does that apply to your problem?

Comment: if that's the case I'll close this question and try the change again within the 24 hour window - hopefully will resolve, thanks